# Initializing a function pointer without the '&' operator

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I was playing around with function pointers, and ran into something that intuitively doesn't fit with my understanding of pointers in C.

Take a look at the following code:

```
include <stdio.h>

void fun(int a) {
    printf("fun, %d!\n", a);

}

void bun(int b) {
    printf("bun, %d!\n", b);
}


int main(){

    void (*fooptr)(int) = &bun;
    void (*blooptr) (int) = fun;

    fooptr(200);
    blooptr(100);

    return 0;
}
```

If I treated function pointers like any other pointer in C, I should expect `void (*blooptr) (int) = fun;` to trigger a compiler warning against incompatible types. My code compiles (silently) and works as expected.

How does C let me initialize a function pointer without the `&` operator, like I would do a regular pointer, without even a compiler warning? Is this one of those cases where I'm accidentally getting the right behaviour, though I'm technically in *undefined behaviour* territory? If someone could explain *why* this works, with some insight (references to literature will also do) into the nature of function pointers, that would be great.

I tried looking around for this specific question, but couldn't find anything related. Seems a bit fundamental, so apologies if it's a dup.

Comment: It's like passing arrays - C reserves the right to be inconsistent, confusing and only require an address operator 'sometimes' :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function type in C automatically and implicitly decays to function pointer type (as if unary `&` operator was quiety applied). This decay takes place in all contexts, with the exception of unary `&` operator and `sizeof` operator. For this reason

```
void (*fooptr)(int) = &bun;
```

and

```
void (*fooptr)(int) = bun;
```

are two alternative ways to say the same thing.

Comment: Could you expand on this part? "This decay takes place in all contexts besides unary & operator and sizeof operator"

Comment: @aspen100: It means that expression `bun` is quietly interpreted as `(void (*)(int)) bun` everywhere, except when you do `&bun` (it is NOT interpreted as `&(void (*)(int)) bun`) and except when you do `sizeof bun` (it is NOT interpreted as `sizeof (void (*)(int)) bun`, it is interpreted as invalid application of `sizeof` instead). In all other contexts `bun` is equivalent to `(void (*)(int)) bun`, which is the same as `&bun`.